# Как в C или C++ вывести круг на экране без использования библиотек?

Tags: c++, c, qt, ассемблер, gtk

Мне интересно как делаются GTK, Qt, wxWidgets.
Мне надо вывести круг и при щелчке на нем он закрывается на C или C++ без использования библиотек различных, то есть как это сделать на чистом C или C++?
Мне сказали, что на чистом C или C++ нельзя сделать, а надо использовать Ассемблер или байт-код? Скажите правильно ли мне ответили?

Comment: Неправильно вам ответили. Вам нужно вычислять координаты точек круга и писать нужный цвет в соответствующее место видеобуфера. (Ну, еще в зависимости от того, на чем именно вы работаете может потребоваться внести код вашей программы в ядро ОС)

Comment: А как это делается? Я хочу это сделать в Федоре, но и как в окнах это сделать тоже интересно. :-)

Comment: В X-windows сделать окошко, установить background и foreground и вывести  им точку можете? Если да, тогда просто считаете, имея координаты центра X, Y и радиус R, где в координатах окошка должны быть точки при изменении X до X + R (симметрично ртображаете каждую еще в 3). Получите круг

Comment: Хочу чтоб было не окно, а только круг и по нажатию мышкой на круг он исчезал. А Вы можете, пожалуйста, написать код C или C++ как это делается без библиотек?

Comment: Без библиотек и ОС это делается написанием собственных аналогов ОС и библиотек. Никаких встроенных возможностей для обработки мышиного ввода или рисования графики в С++ нет.

Comment: А как пишутся собственные библиотеки, на каком языке?

Comment: На C или C++ написана львиная доля библиотек для вывода графики.

Comment: @avp, какой видеобуфер? Современные платформы так заросли в дебрях GPU, что наследие x86 архитектуры уже к ним неприменимо.

Comment: @0andriy, а иногда архитектура бывает такая (не x86), что GPU сам пишет в видеобуфер, напрмер, в hdmi. По разному бывает сделано, поэтому  нужно смотреть как устроен конкретный комп.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, как это делается? :-)

Comment: [Алгоритм Брезенхема для окружности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в примере какой-то другой язык, а как это делается в C или C++ есть ли какой-то аналог функции drawpixel?

Comment: Это зависит от того где вы рисуете. Если на экране устойства или компьютера, то операционная система предоставляет нужные средства. Если картинка в памяти, то есть библиотеки, которые позволяют писать и читать пикселы картинки. Иногда формат такой простой что достаточно прочить документация по графическому формату картинки.